# Read number from text file and display it in a textbox in C#

Tags: c#

I have a text file (ABCD.txt) which contains a number (456700010234) in it. 
The ABCD.txt file contains only the number (456700010234). Nothing else.

I want to display this number in one of the text boxes in C# form.
I prefer not to use a button. Just the textbox in the form/usercontrol.

If anytime I want to change the number, I will just update the text file (ABCD.txt) with a new number and thus, the new number will appear in the textbox automatically each time I open the form. This way, I won't have to re-program the software whenever the number changes. I just want to update the .txt file with a new number if the number changes.

Comment: You need to show us what you've tried first, tell us what's wrong with your attempt (error, unexpected results, etc.), and then we can help you find a working solution. If it doesn't work or doesn't even compile it at least demonstrates that you've tried *something*.

Comment: With all the tutorials available online you should be able to find a very complete answer to your question. The fact that you're asking this questions suggests that you haven't bothered searching.

Comment: A good place to start is reading this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ezwyzy7b.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You first have to create the handler for your `Form_Load` event, like this:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{

}
```

Then you will need to set the `Text` property of the text box to the result of reading all of the data (one line) from the text file, like this:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    YourTextBox.Text = File.ReadAllText("ABCD.txt");
}
```

Now whenever this form loads it will go out and read the contents of that file and display the number in the text file to the user.

Comment: So, I tried the following code:

private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            textBox1.Text = File.ReadAllText("C:\\ABCD.txt");
        }

But, I am getting a blank textbox with no values. Can you help me rectify the problem? It will of great help. thanks.

Answer (score 4):

```
protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnLoad(e);
    textBox1.Text = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\ABCD.txt");
}
```

Comment: So, I tried the following code:

private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            textBox1.Text = File.ReadAllText("C:\\ABCD.txt");
        }

But, I am getting a blank textbox with no values. Can you help me rectify the problem? It will of great help. thanks.

Comment: To fire `textBox1_TextChanged` event, the content of `textBox1` must change. Type a char to textbox and it will load the file.( Of course I know this is not what you want). BTW: Don't you think you should catch some event when file content is changed?

Comment: Awesome! It works. Now the problem is, I need to keyboard-click into textbox every time I want the values to be displayed in the text box. I want the textbox to display the value automatically without me clicking into the text box. So, as soon as I run the program, the form with textbox should show up with values in it from ABCD.txt. This is my last question. Thank a lot!

Comment: @Smith Why do you ask this question? Doesn't your *accepted answer* satisfy your needs. If not, why did you accept it.

Comment: Sorry, I am new to this forum. I apologize. I have removed accepted answer tick.

Comment: @IV4 His answer is perfect. I will choose a accepted answer as soon as I have my last problem solved. :)

My problem: Every time I run the program, the form opens up with the text box. In order to display the values from ABCD.txt in the text box, I need to keyboard-click in the textbox. Then only, the value appear in the textbox from the text file. I want: the textbox to display the values automatically without me/user key-board clicking into the textbox all the time.

Comment: @Smith Karl Anderson's answer using `Form_Load` event is correct, I guess you just copied it without attaching that function to Form Events. I posted a code for dummies. Just copy it and paste to your form.